# How to add bottom border of current row after if statement is true?

Tags: excel, vba

How do I add a bottom border of the current row where the `if` statement is true? I am trying to add a border if a value in a specific cell in the current row equals to `'X'`.

So far I tried to it by conditional formatting, but for some reason, it does not work. I mark entire row (where I need the bottom border) and use "Use a formula to...", then use formula: `=$N$3='X'`. I assume that the table will copy this formatting further, but the thing is no border does show up.

As with coding, I've tried:

```
Public Sub formating()

  Dim rng As Range
  Set rng = Range(ActiveCell.Row)

  If (ActiveCell.Value = x) Then
     With rng.Borders
         .LineStyle = xlContinous
         .Color = vbBlack
         .Weight = xlThin
     End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code you have so far and where you got stuck on. Also if you get an error, include that as well.

Comment: Can easily be done with conditional formatting using a formula. Formula is something like `=$A1="X"`

Comment: @erazorv4, edit'ed, buddy ;)

Comment: I've try'ed, but for some reason it doesn't work... @FunThomas

Comment: Enter the formula you have as formula in a free cell and check what happens.

Comment: Bwt: Your code fails because you compare the active cell with a variable named `x`,not with the string `"X"`

Comment: Or is it possible that table formating and this conditional formating be inflecting one another ?

Comment: No, you can use conditional formatting within a table. If set properly, conditional formatting overrules the table formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ganja, this should be fairly easy to achieve with `Range.Borders` property.

Please see below:

```
If ActiveCell.value = 10 Then
    With ActiveCell.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    End With
End If
```

This would add bottom edge border to the ActiveCell if the value in it was equal to 10. See the difference in our codes and try to apply the `(xlBottomEdge)`You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.borders). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A shorter variant of @JanFusik:

```
With ActiveCell
  .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = IIf(.Value = 10, xlContinuous, .Borders(xlEdgeBottom))
End With
```